# how to add .net 3.5 to visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, addition

I tried to installed visual studio 2010 and it installed .net 4 only. i want to add .net 3.5 to the visual studio.
I have installed the 3.5 and now i'm having problem with add .net 3.5 to the new visual studio. 
how can i add 3.5 to vs 2010?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to "add" .NET 3.5 to VS2010. When you create a new project, you just specify which version of .NET you want to target. (You can change this later, too, in project properties.)

Comment: One question about this, if you don't have .NET 3.5 installed on your computer will it still show up as an alternative as target? Or will VS only list available versions.

Comment: i have specified the version i want to choose , but only .net 4 is availible to me. so how can i add the .net 3.5 now?

Comment: See my answer too, maybe it helps to explicitly install .net 3.5.

Comment: @bloodix: So in the drop-down of framework versions in the project properties, does it not list 3.5? What type of project are you building?

Comment: @Jon: I think I hade the same issue when I installed Visual Studio 2010, I had to install 3.5 separetely. So that's why I'm asking if the framework has to be installed in order to target the framework when implementing the project.

Comment: @Jon: I missed that, then it is sort of strange.

Comment: He probably only installed the runtime via the Windows Update mechanism as opposed to the SDK.

Comment: @ShaneC: That should be enough to build against .NET 3.5 from Visual Studio. Even the compilers etc come as part of the framework.

Comment: @JonSkeet: That would be interesting... but I checked my brand new VS 2010 install and it has 2,3,3.5,4 so yeah.. confused :)  maybe reinstall VS time?

Answer (score 3):

Try this link: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ab99342f-5d1a-413d-8319-81da479ab0d7&displaylang=en

It is the download package for .NET 3.5. Maybe you don't have 3.5 installed.

Also read Jon's answer.

**EDIT:** Updated link to point to .NET 3.5 SP 1 instead as Hans points out.

Comment: Don't install old versions, 3.5 SP1 is current.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so now I understand what happend when installing on Visual Studio 2008. Apparently the 3.5 framework is not installed by default (at least they do not install it by default here where I work. VS2010 does not install 3.5 for you - you have to install it using Windows Server Manager. Once you do then 3.5 will install and you will immediately be able to retarget your projects in VS.

Answer (score 0):

.NET FRAMEWORK 4 contains all precedents versions.
Just target your project in properties of your application in VS2010